# pointcloud_to_laserscan

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

how can i start [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) package ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54857/pointcloud_to_laserscan/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-02-11**:
Depends on what you want to do with it - what exactly are you trying to do?

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-03-22**:
@allenh1, I want to run SLAM and I've installed openni_camera and openni_launch till now, I want to install pcl_to_laserscan and then install either gmapping or hectorSLAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This launch file might help

```
<launch>
<!-- kinect and frame ids -->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
 <!-- openni_manager -->
 <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>
<!-- throttling -->
 <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
 <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
 <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
<remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
 </node>

 <!-- fake laser -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
<param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
<remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-03-22**:
@shade @tfoote How do I use this launch file? Where do I keep it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By running the node and publishing your clouds to the *cloud* topic. The scans will be published on the *scan* topic.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have an easier time (and use less CPU) if you use [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan).

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1